# Visual studio extensions and updates never retrieves information

Tags: visual-studio, internet-connection, general-network-error

I have installed visual studio 2013 , and because I was not able to download any package from package manager , I thought that problem is from the visual then I uninstalled it and installed vs 2017 but still not connecting

for example when I go to Extensions and updates it just stuck here
[image]

at the end I get this message:

a connection to the server could not be established because the following error(s) occurred: the operation time out

Comment: Please be a lot more specific about what your problem and question really is about.

Comment: thank you very much I already updated